# How can I manage exception when using external processes in scala?

Tags: scala, process

When running a external command, exceptions are simply displayed to the std output. How can I manage them from inside the code ?

Example :

```
import sys.process._
("yes -y 100" #| "head -c 1").!
```

I simply get the following stacktrace.

```
java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
at java.io.PipedInputStream.checkStateForReceive(PipedInputStream.java:261)
at java.io.PipedInputStream.awaitSpace(PipedInputStream.java:269)
at java.io.PipedInputStream.receive(PipedInputStream.java:232)
at java.io.PipedOutputStream.write(PipedOutputStream.java:149)
at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$.loop$1(BasicIO.scala:236)
at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$.transferFullyImpl(BasicIO.scala:242)
at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$.transferFully(BasicIO.scala:223)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessImpl$PipeThread.runloop(ProcessImpl.scala:159)
at scala.sys.process.ProcessImpl$PipeSource.run(ProcessImpl.scala:179)
```

Any try catch seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Printing to stdout is what .! does. You will need to use .! with custom process logger, i.e.:

```
import scala.sys.process._
("yes -y 100" #| "head -c 1").!(new ProcessLogger {
    override def buffer[T](f: => T): T = f
    override def out(s: => String): Unit = ()
    override def err(s: => String): Unit = ()
})
```

.... or just .!! to get a string

Comment: Ah, I see, I was confused by the -y not existing on linux. Anyway from the stacktrace I see in the source that this is quite difficult to circumvent. See https://github.com/scala/legacy-svn-scala/blob/master/src/library/scala/sys/process/ProcessImpl.scala line 159

Comment: ... and very much the same in last version https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/sys/process/ProcessImpl.scala